# How to download a video hyperlink

Tags: google-chrome

Okay, so I know this sounds a bit simple.

But I have a link:
https://vt.tumblr.com/tumblr_npem0kfJBA1qg8a8q.mp4

Fine?  But in Google Chrome, if I click that link, it loads it in the browser and plays the video.  Now how do I download that link as an MP4 file, (which is what it is), in Chrome?

The only way I can think is to make a small html page with an  tag with the href pointing to that, and then right click and save link as.  There must be an easier way.

Comment: What's wrong with right clicking the link in your question and save as? Problem solved ;)

Comment: Well, if you really not want to right click and select download as, you could still rewrite the left click funtion (javascript) on your small html website so it does the right click but on left click.